# Exporting output in ASCII from a QGIS model

Tags: qgis, algorithm, ascii, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to find a geoalgorithm in QGIS's Graphical Modeler that can convert and export a vector to ASCII. Could anyone enlighten me if there's an option for that? Perhaps through some script but I really don't know where to start. I'm guessing one that uses some translation tool from GDAL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if I enter the .asc ending for the output file it will generate an ASCII file. However, it would be nice to know another way as well.

Comment: Not you question nor your answer does give me a clue what you are talking about...

Comment: @BerndV. What I wanted to know if it is possible to export in ASCII format. However, it's not working as I expected. It doesn't export as well as ArcGIS.